# What is the most efficient way of creating a password protected Rmarkdown document online?

Tags: r-markdown, password-protection

Ideally I would be able to present RMarkdown document with the only extra layer being that there is a password prompt before viewers to my link can view it.

It would be very useful to be able to password protect class related Rmarkdown documents, but I am unable to find any guidance on the matter.